# Forced server-side socket close without SO_LINGER > 0 can lose data, right?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets

I'm writing a cross-platform client application that uses sockets, written in C++. I'm having problems where the server is doing a hard close on the socket when it's done sending me info.

I've been reading other posts on this topic, and I'm not so much interested in the rights or wrong of this approach, but it's seems the server is either explicitly setting SO_LINGER=0, or that's the default behavior on that system (not sure, it's a Linux box).

I can see (in Wireshark) that the data was sent to me followed within milli-seconds by an RST, indicating a hard close by the server. I personally don't agree with this approach as it should be up to the client to shutdown the socket.

Server team are saying there's nothing wrong with that approach (doing a hard close rather than shutdown), it's typical on servers to avoid accumulating TIMED_WAIT sockets. On Windows my `select()` returns indicating there's something to read (while I haven't read any of this "in transit" data yet).

However, because of the quick arrival of the RST, on Windows `recv()` returns -1 and I'm seeing a 10054 for the error code (connection reset by peer). This wouldn't be too bad if I could at least get the data that was sent, but it seems that once my client's socket stack sees the RST any unread bytes are no longer made available to me.

On Linux (client), there's no problem. It seems the TCP stack is behaving slightly differently, in that I can read the outstanding bytes before the RST is honoured. I'm having trouble convincing the server guys they have a bug, given that it works for a Linux client.

First off, am I correct? Is this a server-side issue? I can't see that the client end is doing anything wrong, so it must be right?

It seems the server team are adamant that they want to perform the close, and they don't want to in have TIMED_WAITs, so I was going to push for them to add a SO_LINGER of, say 2 seconds? Does that sound like it will solve my problem? From what I understand this will stop the server from sending out a RST so soon after sending data, and should give me a chance to read the outstanding bytes.

Comment: You're talking about an RST an a FIN. Which one do you receive?

Comment: Just a RST. The server is doing a hard close (a socket close, with no shutdown before it)

Comment: Closing side (server) definitely has no incoming data that it hadn't read. The bytes that it sends me confirms this, as it's the correct response to the bytes I sent. From my reading in MSDN "Any data in the output window which has not been acknowledged is discarded, a reset is sent to the remote host and closesocket returns immediately...". By acknowledged I'm thinking they mean recv got them on the other end. Not sure what discarded means from the perspective of the other end. It's possible "discarded" includes invalidating any recv() attempt to read data on the other end.

Comment: If the server is closing with SO_LINGER set to 0 and deliberately aiming for TIME_WAIT assassination then they really shouldn't be also sending data that they hope that will get to you. Can you change the application level protocol so that they can send you the data you need and then you can send them an "OK please close the connection now" message and then they do the RST?

Comment: Note that this approach is unreliable even with a Linux client.  If the network happens to drop the last packet, the server won't be able to retransmit it.

Comment: @LenHolgate It would be more to the point for the client to close first. Then TIME_WAIT happens at the client, not the server.

Answer (score 2):

The side-effect of fiddling with SO_LINGER to force a reset is that all pending data is lost. The fact that you don't receive it is all the proof you need that the server team is wrong to do this.

RFC 793 cited below says 'this command [ABORT] causes all pending SENDs and RECEIVEs to be aborted, ... and a special RESET message to be sent to the TCP on the other side of the connection.' See also W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* Vol. 1, p. 287:  'Aborting a connection provides two features to the application: (1) any queued data is thrown away and the reset is sent immediately, and (2) the receiver of the RST can tell that the other end did an abort instead of a normal close'. There is similar wording, along with an extract from the BSD code that implements it, in Vol. 2.

The TIME_WAIT state only occurs on a socket which sends a FIN before it has received one: see [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt). So the server should be waiting for a FIN from the client, with a suitable timeout, rather than resetting. This will also permit the client to do connection pooling.

Comment: The fact that it happens that way on Windows and doesn't on Linux seems to indicate that the behaviour is open to interpretation. I was hoping there was something to prove that it's not undefined.

Comment: I think you'll find that you're actually talking about FIN_WAIT2. TIME_WAIT is always entered by the side that issues the active close. See http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Comment: Not sure. Server isn't sending me a FIN, so I don't think it enters the TIME-WAIT state. From what I understand this is something that some server endpoints do if they fear having too many TIME-WAIT sockets. Sending a RST avoid TIME-WAIT from what understand, but runs the risk of transmitted data disappearing in the ether. An immediate RST is only really warranted when the server really wants to reject a client, for example if they don't the data they're getting, or see you as a bogus client, and are denying the client any further access, from what I can tell.

Comment: @user1849763 The semantics of RST are 'no such connection'. Any pending data at both the sender and the receiver of the RST is discarded. Any difference in behaviour between platforms would be due to socket send/receive buffer sizes only, which are on aWindows, large on Unix/Linux.

Comment: @LenHolgate 'The side that issues the active close' and 'a socket that sends a FIN and hasn't received one' are the same thing.

Comment: Just on the comment about the buffer size; the server is sending me 10 bytes (payload), just before the RST. It's just these 10 bytes I don't get to receive. I don't think it's a buffer size issue.

Comment: EJP - My point was that `FIN_WAIT2` is the state that a socket that has sent a FIN but hasn't received one is in. `TIME_WAIT` is entered after that socket HAS received the FIN that it is expecting.

Comment: @LenHolgate Minor rewording above should take care of that.

Comment: Cool. Sorry, I was being pedantic because there was a slight difference between what you meant and what you original said :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a definitive answer to my own question:

"...Upon reception of RST segment, the receiving side will immediately abort the connection. This statement has more implications than just meaning that you will not be able to receive or send any more data to/from this connection. **It also implies that any unread data still in the TCP reception buffer will be lost**..." It cites the book "TCP/IP Internetworking Volume II". I don't have that book, so I can only take his word for it. Doesn't seems to discard data on Linux, only Windows...

[Olivier Langlois's blog](http://blog.olivierlanglois.net/index.php/2010/02/06/tcp_rst_flag_subtleties)

Comment: An Internet bog is no more 'definitive' that the answers you get here. *Stevens* is authoritative, the *RFC* is definitive.

Comment: I agree. If anyone has the two books quoted it would be great if they could cite the exact text from one of the books.